# Getting the width and height of a div or image after it finished loading

Tags: javascript, html, image, height, width

I'm creating an image gallery and I need to know the size of the div containing the image or the image itself after it loads.  How can I get that?   I've tried everything but it gives me the size of the DIV before it loads, which is 1px X 1px.

Basically everything is hidden, you click a link and the image displays, so the div goes from 1px by 1px to for example, say 419px by 1000px.   How do I get that final size after the DIV or Image loads? the size can change depending on the device used and the image loaded.  Is there anyway to get this information using just JavaScript?

Here's the function. If possible I would like to get the height of the image or the DIV after the image loads in the same function.

here's the function that i am testing

```
function ShowArt(nam,imgs,)
 { 
     
 var currentPosition = parseInt(movingDivObj.style.top);
 var scrollPos = window.scrollY || window.scrollTop || document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].scrollTop; 
 

   movingDivObj.style.top = currentPosition + scrollPos + "px";
   
   
   movingDivObj.style.display = "block";
   document.getElementById("close").style.display = "block";
   document.getElementById("selectedart").style.display = "block";
   document.getElementById("artname").style.display = "block";
   document.getElementById("background").style.display = "block";
   
   display.src = imgs;
   
   document.getElementById("artname").textContent= nam;
   
   scrollPosition  = window.pageYOffset;
   document.body.style.position = "fixed";
   document.body.style.top = `-${scrollPosition}px`;

 }
```

Thanks!

Comment: do you have any sample code? what have you tried to resolve the issues?

Comment: I'm not really sure how to go about getting it. Some code I've tried conflicts with other code and the image won't even load.   But I've tried something simple like    var test4 = document.getElementById("myimg").offsetHeight; alert(test4);   which gives me the beginning height of the DIV box.  I need to know the height after it loads the image.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this DOM event listener, in the callback function you can write the necessary code to get your value I presume:[here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event)

Answer (score 0):

In the same way that the "load" event works for the body, it works for images. So you could attach an "load" event on the image and when it triggers, measure the width/height.

```
const img = document.querySelector('#img')
img.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
  console.log('width', event.target.width)
  console.log('height', event.target.height)
})

img.src = 'https://via.placeholder.com/900x1000'
```

Comment: I need to know the width / height so I can use that info in the same code to center it on the page. Is this possible? Basically i need to get the width / height and then use that same info in the same function to set the top and side positions if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
  <script>
    var myImg = document.getElementById('image');
            var realWidth = myImg.naturalWidth;
            var realHeight = myImg.naturalHeight;
    console.log(realWidth);
    </script>
```

Comment: I need to know the width / height so I can use that info in the same code to center it on the page.  Is this possible?   Basically i need to get the width / height and then use that same info in the same function to set the top and side positions if possible.

Comment: do you mean of the page 0r the image because if you want the page size its:       var win = window,
    doc = document,
    docElem = doc.documentElement,
    body = doc.getElementsByTagName('body')[0],
    x = win.innerWidth || docElem.clientWidth || body.clientWidth,
    y = win.innerHeight|| docElem.clientHeight|| body.clientHeight;
alert(x + ' × ' + y);

Comment: The image, basically I have a function something like  function MyImg(name, img) where it passes the name of the art piece and the img src.   In the function it sets the display and makes everything visible.  In that same function, I want to get the height of the div or image after it loads.  Right now it's giving me the height of the div or image before it load the image fully.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution 1:

Use this Solution in your JS file

JavaScript:

```js
window.onload = () => {};//enter the code that gets the image or divs width and height in the {} brackets`
```

The window.onload function waits till the DOM is loaded and then executes a function. It is used mostly when you need to get default values from a predefined and static element.
Further Readings: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp

## Solution 2:

NOTE: Use this only if you are using a 'script' tag to use the JS code in your HTML.
Use the script tag at the end of your HTML document

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <!--Your code goes here-->
  <script src="myScript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys I appreciate all the help.  I finally found an answer that worked though I got some great ideas.  The answer was to have the images preload and when I did that it gave me the height of the image I needed for the next steps.   Again thanks very much! I appreciate it.  The code I used for this is below. After the images are preloaded I am able to get the width / height of the images so they work in the gallery as planned.    It worked like a charm.

```
var images = new Array()
function preload() {
    for (i = 0; i < preload.arguments.length; i++) {
        images[i] = new Image()
        images[i].src = preload.arguments[i]
                }
        }
    preload(
        "Photos/AloneInTheStorm.jpg",
        "Photos/deepinthought.jpg",
        "Photos/68degrees.jpg",
        "Photos/forgotten.jpg",
        "Photos/babylycan2.jpg",
        "Photos/americancoot.jpg"
        )
```